# Change value of attributes in a form field in Yii2

Tags: php, html, yii2

i have a simple question, that is how can i change the attributes values of a a field of an ActiveForm in Yii2

For example:

The following code :

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'name'); ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'email') ?>

    <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton('Submit', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
    </div>

<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

generates this :

```
<input id="testform-email" class="form-control" name="TestForm[email]" aria-required="true" type="text">
```

I want to change the **name** and **id** attributes to a custom value.

Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried yourself...? Show effort.

Comment: i tried overriding the fields methods, but i'm not sure that's the way, could you help me a little. Thanks in advance.

Comment: ..that's a start for usefulness info and should be edited into your question.Keep in mind.. we can't look inside your head and see what you tried so far ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could assign directly the attribute you need  this way

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'name')->textInput(['id' => 'your_id', 'name' => 'your_name']); ?>
```